# maps between classifying spaces of homotopy associative H-spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be an H-map between homotopy associative H-spaces in the homotopy category of based CW-complexes. It's well-known that there is an induced H-map from the homotopy fibre $F$ of $f$ to $X$; that is, there is a homotopy fibration of H-spaces and H-maps:
$$\Omega Y\xrightarrow{\partial} F\xrightarrow{i} X\xrightarrow{f}Y.$$
Suppose that $F$ is also homotopy associative and let $\mathcal{B}F$ be the classifying space of $F$. My **question** is: Under what conditions that there is an induced map $\mathcal{B}\partial\colon Y\to\mathcal{B}F$ such that the fibration extends from the right as
$$\cdots\to F\xrightarrow{i} X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{\mathcal{B}\partial}\mathcal{B}F.$$

I know it is always true if $X,Y$ are topological groups, while from Page 31 of Stasheff's book "H-spaces from a homotopy point of view" I read that an H-map doesn't necessarily induces a map between the classifying spaces. I didn't find the answers to the question in Stasheff's book.

Comment: It doesn't follow that $F$ has a classifying space. For this it needs an $A_\infty$ structure, not just an $A_3$-structure. If $X,Y$ are $A_\infty$-spaces, then a H-map $X\rightarrow Y$ deloops if and only if it is an $A_\infty$-map.

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks! Could you please recommend some references about these facts.

Comment: I like the paper [*Higher Homotopy Associativity*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0085229) by Iwase and Mimura

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks a lot!